# Curl request error (52) from docker container but works on host

Tags: windows, docker, http, curl, containers

I am running a Linux (Debian based) docker container on a Windows host.
I have a device with an HTTP based API that I want to interface with from the container.

When I run the curl command to the devices API under WSL from my host machine, it responds correctly.

```
<username>@<hostname>:/mnt/c/Users/$ curl -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46aGVybW9zYTA=" http://172.16.255.33/Set.cmd?CMD=GetPower -v
*   Trying 172.16.255.33:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 172.16.255.33 (172.16.255.33) port 80 (#0)
> GET /Set.cmd?CMD=GetPower HTTP/1.1
> Host: 172.16.255.33
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46aGVybW9zYTA=
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
< Connection: close
<
<html>p61=1,p62=1,p63=0,p64=0</html>
* Closing connection 0
```

However, when I do the same curl command from my container, I get the error `(52) Empty reply from server`

```
root@9af1adf97ba7:/# curl -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46aGVybW9zYTA=" http://172.16.255.33/Set.cmd?CMD=GetPower -v
*   Trying 172.16.255.33:80...
* Connected to 172.16.255.33 (172.16.255.33) port 80 (#0)
> GET /Set.cmd?CMD=GetPower HTTP/1.1
> Host: 172.16.255.33
> User-Agent: curl/7.74.0
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46aGVybW9zYTA=
>
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host 172.16.255.33 left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

In Wireshark, I see the device is setting the RST flag in its response when queried from the container.  No such reset in the response when queried from my host machine.
[image]

I am starting my container using these arguments:
`docker run -it -p 80:80 <image-name> bash`

When I start to run the container on a Linux host using the same args, the curl request succeeds (as a test, I have to run this app on a Windows host).

I have tried both WSL2 based and Hyper-V based versions of Docker on Windows.

Under WSL2 container, I get no response from the device.
Under Hyper-V based container, I get the issue described above.

I've spent about a day Googling and trying various things, and I am out of ideas at this point.
Thanks.

Comment: I am sure my issue is a quirk of running a linux container on a windows host. Since curl to the device in the same container on a linux host works fine. And curl from a windows container on this windows host also works.

Comment: I just verified I can telnet into the device from the container running on Windows.  Why is curl and HTTP not working?